# How can I use python pandas to parse CSV into the format I want?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm new to python pandas. I have a CSV file like this:

```
insectName   count   weather  location   time        date      Condition
  aaa         15      sunny   balabala  0900:1200   1990-02-10     25
  bbb         10      sunny   balabala  0900:1200   1990-02-10     25
  ccc         20      sunny   balabala  0900:1200   1990-02-10     25
  ddd         50      sunny   balabala  0900:1200   1990-02-10     25
  ...        ...      ...      ...        ...            ...       ...
  XXX         40      sunny   balabala  1300:1500   1990-02-15     38
  yyy         10      sunny   balabala  1300:1500   1990-02-15     38
  yyy         25      sunny   balabala  1300:1500   1990-02-15     38
```

the file have many data and the insectName in every day could repeat.
I want to translate the data use by 'date' ,one day in a row.
like this:

```
insectName  count  insectName  count  insectName  count  weather  location  time        date      Condition
  ccc         20      bbb       10       aaa        15    sunny   balabala  0900:1200   1990-02-10     25
  yyy         25      yyy       10       XXX        40    sunny   balabala  1300:1500   1990-02-15     38
  ...        ...      ...      ...       ...        ...    ...      ...        ...            ...        ...
```

How could I do?

Comment: Are there always an equal amount of rows per 'date'? (so the number of columns in the desired result will be constant?)

Comment: Yes . And the only changes are 'insectName' and 'count' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `groupby/cumcount/unstack` trick which converts long-format DataFrames to wide-format DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')

common = ['weather', 'location', 'time', 'date', 'Condition']
grouped = df.groupby(common)
df['idx'] = grouped.cumcount()
df2 = df.set_index(common+['idx'])
df2 = df2.unstack('idx')
df2 = df2.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
df2 = df2.sortlevel(axis=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print(df2)
```

yields

```
  weather  location       time        date  Condition insectName  count  \
0   sunny  balabala  0900:1200  1990-02-10         25        aaa     15   
1   sunny  balabala  1300:1500  1990-02-15         38        XXX     40   

  insectName  count insectName  count insectName  count  
0        bbb     10        ccc     20        ddd     50  
1        yyy     10        yyy     25        NaN    NaN
```

While wide-format may be useful for presentation, note that long-format
is usually the right format for data processing. See Hadley Wickham's [article on the virtues of tidy data (PDF)](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: Change `df = pd.read_table('data', ...)` to `df = pd.read_table('/path/to/csv', ...)` where `/path/to/csv` is the path to your CSV file.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I have got the format I want.  can I write the format  to  a new CSV file?

Comment: See the `to_csv` method

Comment: @unutbu  Sorry , I got a problem again. I tried to expand my data ,and use the code you provide to translate the format I want. But I got an error , ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed. And this is an example CSV file, https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SUWnrBmDwSUzZGT3pLUE5qSXc&authuser=0 ,can you help again ? Thank you very much.

Comment: `birds.csv` is 234M. Please post a smaller file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @unutbu Sorry, my fault. Here is the smaller file with the same problem,but the file is in Chinese language,is it OK?     https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SUWnrBmDwSUWtUc0h1eG8wZXc&authuser=0

Comment: 57M is smaller but still much much too large. Keep on bisecting the file until you have a *minimal* example of what is causing the problem.

Comment: 36M is the most smaller,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SUWnrBmDwSZEw4TlBjaEI4a3c&authuser=0, "15,000" web datas. Less 15,000 it will get another error  ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Bisection is a useful technique when debugging: Read in your csv file with `df =
pd.read_csv(...)`. Find the length, `N = len(df)`. Now split df into two roughly
equal pieces: `df1, df2 = df.iloc[:N//2], df.iloc[-N//2:]`. Run your code on each
of these two pieces, `df1` and `df2`. On at least one of these DataFrames you will
get an error. Now split this problematic DataFrame into two and repeat. Keep
repeating until you have a DataFrame less than 10 rows and which exhibits the
problem. Having this skill will make you a more independent programmer.

Comment: @unutbu Thanks for your solution. I found a new problem in my data set. It's  "date",because I ask only use "date" at first. I didn't find the same "date" and " Condition" at one day , it makes the code go wrong. Can I use "date" and "time" with the same code ?

Comment: I don't understand the situation. Please post a new question with a runnable example and the desired output.